# Same controller, different template, one new variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a page where I display data (www.mypage.com/:gameId). To print this data I want to show a print friendly page (www.mypage.com/:gameId/print). Both of the pages are identical in data output but different in appearance. I need to hide the root header and root footer of the page when in print view, for that I can use ng-show. Now, how can I call ng-show=false when print page is loaded.

Right now I have this, but it obviously doesn't work (tried multiple controllers). Print controller calls "$rootScope.hide_for_print = false;"

```
    .when('/:gameId', {
        controller: 'game',
        templateUrl: 'views/gamePage.html'
    })

    .when('/:gameId/print', {
        controller: 'game, print',
        templateUrl: 'views/gamePrint.html'
    })
```

Comment: Do you want to use a diff controller? or the same game controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change the route to pick up `print` option as well :-

```
 .when('/:gameId/:print', {
    controller: 'game',
    templateUrl: 'views/gamePrint.html'
});
```

and  inject `$routeParams` in your controller and set the flag

```
  $scope.hide_for_print = $routeParams.print;
```

Comment: Wow, that's clever. Thanks, exactly what I needed :D

Comment: Also for anyone who is going to use this solution use "ng-hide="hide_for_print" instead of ng-show="hide_for_print"